# Why doesn't work I18n.locale and redirect_back?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to make an eternal fixed locale in the site URL. That is, the locale parameter should always be in the site URL.

In ApplicationController I added this code:

```rb
def default_url_options
  { locale: I18n.locale }
end
```

In theory, I should now always have the locale parameter in all URLs. Right? But why is this not happening? The first thing I need is to have the locale parameter absolutely always in the URL inside the specific namespace.

Next I have this controller:

```rb
class Public::BaseController < ApplicationController
  layout 'public'

  around_action :prepare_locale

  private

  def prepare_locale(&action)
    received_locale = params[:locale].presence || I18n.default_locale

    if I18n.available_locales.include?(received_locale.to_sym)
      I18n.with_locale(received_locale, &action)
    else
      I18n.with_locale(I18n.default_locale, &action)
    end
  end
end
```

And this code, which is responsible for changing the locale parameter:

```rb
class Service::LanguagesController < Service::BaseController
  def change
    received_locale = params[:new_locale].presence || I18n.default_locale

    redirect_back(
      fallback_location: root_path,
      allow_other_host: false,
      params: {  # this is to make sure
        locale: received_locale
      },
      locale: received_locale
    )
  end
end
```

As a result, `params[:new_locale]` has a new locale. But `redirect_back` doesn't change anything. Why?

This code works:

```rb
redirect_to root_path(locale: received_locale)
```

But this option doesn't fit, as it is inconvenient.

In total, I don't understand how I can do what I intended.

Answer (score -1):

I looked at rails internals and saw that `redirect_back` is a `redirect_to` passing `referrer` as first argument. [See here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f675cb30ce813a99b52b139a93e048330922fd9a/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb#L93)

But in that case the `params` passed to `redirect_to` are ignored because it's just an `String`.

I suggest you to use `redirect_to` instead and pass locale explicit.